# What is the Otherway of adding a row to the Existing Html Table(jquery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

iam adding no of rows to the Existing Html table  based on the value inputted from user in a textbox.

```
$('#btn_add').click(function(){                 
            //This would get the complete last row in the html table 
            tr= $("#tbl tr:last").html();
            //This is the input for the no of rows  
            num= $('#noofrowstxtbox').val()*1;          
            //This would give the last row value .Say if 2 rows are there in a table it would give "2"
            x = $("#tbltr:last").attr('id').substr(4)*1;
            //Say for x is "2" and the rows we want to add is "1" then last will become "3"
            last=x+num;                                 
            for(i=x+1;i<=last;i++) {
                var newtr= tr.replace(x,i); 
                newtr= newtr.replace('sno'+x,'sno'+i);              
                newtr= newtr.replace('sname'+x,'sname'+i);
                newtr= newtr.replace('saddress'+x,'saddress'+i);
                $('#tbl').append('<tr id="st_'+i+'">'+newtr+'</tr>');
            }
```

but Here iam Replacing the last row and adding it .Is there any way to do more efficiently

Comment: What are `sno`, `sname` and `saddress`? Is there any chance you could give the HTML of a table row?

Comment: @lonesomeday: Those are text fields that are added to each row

Comment: So they are ID attributes? Please be explicit about what you need, rather than making us guess!

Comment: Can you add your table HTML?! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
$("#btn-add").click(function(){
    var noOfRowsToBeAdded = parseInt($("#noofrowstxtbox").val());
    var rowsArray = new Array();
    for (i=0; i < noOfRowsToBeAdded; i++) {
        rowsArray.push("<tr><td>content</td></tr>");
    }

    $("#tbl").append(rowsArray.join());
});
```

Comment: Combine this solution with your string replace statements for your input ids and you are golden.

Comment: Word of caution with parseInt....make sure you specify that you expect decimal values....parseInt("010") != 10......parseInt("010",10) == 10

Answer (score 0):

try something like that also:

```
$table.children('tbody').append(row);
```